# What is D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am on the verge of publishing my app and this lines(below) is just causing me a lot of headaches as there are some important outputs I have to check in the run console.

What exactly is this D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0.How can I stop  it .Some answer said it is a problem with admob,so how do I get rid of it

```
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
D/AudioManager(12346): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it happens if you use banner ad from admob.. To check other outputs you can check the logcat from Android studio and filter through your expected output.

Comment: how to filter through the expected output?I mean in  logcat there is much more stuff to read 
  @MRN